# How to GET data of a key in json using curl?

Tags: json, curl

Sorry Pretty noob to json.

Basically I have a simple server where I can upload data in there.

E.g:

```
curl -vX PUT "http://IP:port/ABC" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @"Once Upon a time."
```

After when I do:

```
curl -vX GET "http://IP:port/ABC" -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

I get:

```
{"reverse_shell":
  {"aliases":{},"mappings":{},"settings":
    {"index":{"creation_date":"1561863982371","number_of_shards":"5","number_of_replicas":"1","uuid":"IAWE83rYQqmtKW-9svkBVg","version":{"created":"6040299"},"provided_name":"ABC"}
   }
 }
}
```

As you can see there is no where mentioning `Once Upon a time`, so is there I am missing? or how do I get that data from json using curl?

I am in kali linux env.

Comment: You seem to be asking us to help you understand the REST semantics of a service you have not specified or given us access to.  This is unanswerable.  It is equivalent to saying "I asked my neighbor to take care of my cat when I was on vacation.  I came home and the cat was gone.  My neighbor won't tell me anything about my cat.  Where is my cat?"

Comment: @John Zwinck. That is kind of a gentle way of asking for more information.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Are you expecting a peice of code handling my requests in back-end?

Comment: @creepy: We either need to see the code of the backend service, or better yet the documentation for the backend service.  Do you have the documentation?  Or do you have a contact person who operates the service whom you can ask for help?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Unfortunately All I have is the front-end :( I assume there is not much you gys can do then ?

Comment: If you're using a service with no documentation and no support available, there's nothing we can do but make wild guesses.  At least if you told us what service it was we could try to find more information, but you've hidden that information from us.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to post a string as a file.

When you specify a "@" with -d this tells curl to send the data from a file called "Once Upon a time."

If you are trying to put a file then you should do:

**my_text_file.txt**

```
Once Upon a time.
```

curl -vX PUT "http://IP:port/ABC" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @./my_text_file.txt https://server/api/path